# Flag rows with same values on x and y but different value on z

Tags: sas, unique, enterprise-guide

In SAS Enterprise, I am trying to identify any person with the same value on x and y but a different value on z (z are supposed to be the same but some people have more than one value of z).

One way to do this would be to sort on x, y, z - but can anyone suggest a way to flag instances of z within x and y that differ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear with what you require, some sample data would be helpful to make the question clearer. However, I've made an attempt at answering anyway. So, assuming your input table is called `my_table`, the following code creates two datasets giving you the results you need.

```
/* The flagged table contains just those x,y groups with differing z */
proc sql;
  create table flagged as
  select 
  x,
  y
  from my_table
  group by x,y
  having count(distinct z) > 1;
quit;

/* Join the flagged table back to the original table to get the z values back */
proc sql;
  create table flagged_all as
  select
  f.x,
  f.y,
  a.z
  from 
  my_table as a
  inner join
  flagged f
  on a.x = f.x
  and a.y = f.y;
quit;
```

EDIT: Or you can accomplish this using a sub-select:

```
proc sql;
  create table flagged_all as
  select
  f.x,
  f.y,
  a.z
  from 
  my_table as a
  inner join
  (select 
  x,
  y
  from my_table
  group by x,y
  having count(distinct z) > 1) f
  on a.x = f.x
  and a.y = f.y;
quit;
```

However, this reduces the readability of the code. To get the same functionality, you could replace the `flagged` table in the first version with a view (`create view flagged as...`).

Comment: Is there a way to do everything in one step, by inserting a dummy variable (0 vs. 1) into the original table if any of the values of z differ for those with the same x and y value (e.g. INSERT INTO SELECT)?

Comment: I think it's best to keep it as a query (i.e. not changing the existnig data). The two steps in my answer could be combined. See edit...

Comment: If I wanted to add another restriction using WHERE (e.g. WHERE variable1!=1), where does the WHERE statement go? I tried putting it after HAVING COUNT and it didn't work. Thank you.